# Meaning of 'average crowd of humans'

Tags: meaning

Does 'average crowd of humans' mean 'common people'? 
Here is the example, which is from 'Baker's blue-jay yarn' by Mark Twain.

*They all examined the hole, they all made the sufferer tell it over again, then they all discussed it, and got off as many leather-headed opinions about it as* ***an average crowd of humans*** *could have done.*

Comment: If, on any street corner, some hubbub caused people to gather round to gawk, you would find there a "cross-section" of society.  It would be "an average crowd".  You might find in such a crowd a doctor, a baker, a wheelwright, a barber, a mother, a war veteran, a child, an ex-convict.

Comment: @TRomano I wish to vote that up as an answer. :)

Comment: @Damkerng T. As you wish :)

Answer (score 3):

If, on any street corner, some hubbub caused people to gather round to gawk, you would find there a "cross-section" of society. It would be "an average crowd". You might find in such a crowd a doctor, a baker, a wheelwright, a barber, a mother, a war veteran, a child, an ex-convict.